# SVN: Re-add an accidentally deleted empty folder?

Tags: svn

I have a cache-like folder (called "minified") that holds minified css files. The files inside are not part of svn but the folder itself is. When the files inside are deleted, a script knows to recreate them from the non-minified versions.

However, when doing this delete of css files, I accidentally deleted the "minified" folder. Since it is empty in svn and thus rather trivial, I figure it should be possible to re-add it in. Is this possible and how should I go about it? This happened on a remote server, not my local dev machine.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Might `svn update` do the trick?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that re-adds it. But I don't see any .svn files in the folder so I don't think it worked properly? I should clarify that I'm a bit of a subversion noob.

Comment: if no `.svn` is here, delete again the directory and do `svn up`

Comment: Both right. I stupid. Feel free to close. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you didn't make a `svn ci` to commit your accident, a simple `svn revert minifield` or `svn update` should be enough.

If you simply removed/recreated the directory, delete it again, and then run `svn update` it should repair the problem and recreate the `.svn` directory

Comment: Totally right. Thanks guys. I just get super nervous when working with SVN even though it's supposed to do the opposite.

Comment: I'm curious about `minifield` - what does it do?

Comment: Specialized minification function. Only works on form fields.